# Disable viminfo completely

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm trying to disable viminfo completely, I tried to add something in the ~/.vimrc,

I tried 3 different methods, none of them works

```
set viminfo='0,:0,<0,@0,f0,n~/.viminfo
set viminfo=
set viminfo="None"
```

Any ideas? I just don't want viminfo to record what files was edited before

The vim version is:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Dec 10 2016 23:06:12)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-130
Compiled by Homebrew
```

Comment: `set viminfo=` should do it.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Hmm, does not work for me ..

Comment: Now, _that_ is an useful description of a problem. :)

Comment: Could you please accept one of these answers, if possible?

Answer (score 11):

Try invoking Vim with

```
$ vim -i NONE
```

From `:help -i`:

> ```
> -i {viminfo}    The file "viminfo" is used instead of the default viminfo
>                 file.  If the name "NONE" is used (all uppercase), no viminfo
>                 file is read or written, even if 'viminfo' is set or when
>                 ":rv" or ":wv" are used.
> ```

Comment: This along with `set clipboard=exclude:.*` made it run faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Hope it ain't too late, but I think I figured out how to disable this.

Seems that Vim 8 is enabling the `viminfo` feature by default (maybe another features are enabled by default that were disabled on previous versions of Vim). So you need to put in your `~/.vimrc` or the new `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` file (if you want to set this as global - you'll need to create that file if you don't have one) the following:

```
let skip_defaults_vim=1
set viminfo=""
```

The `skip_defaults_vim` tells Vim not to load the default Vim configuration file, `defaults.vim` (for example, located on my Gentoo box at /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim).

Hope this works on your Mac, as that was driving me insane.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
set viminfofile=NONE
```

From the documentation ([`:help viminfo-file-name`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html?#viminfo-file-name)):

```
- The "-i" Vim argument can be used to set another file name, |-i|.  When the
  file name given is "NONE" (all uppercase), no viminfo file is ever read or
  written.  Also not for the commands below!
- The 'viminfofile' option can be used like the "-i" argument.  In fact, the
  value form the "-i" argument is stored in the 'viminfofile' option.
```